# String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

After upgrading from VS 2013 Update 4 to Update 5
I am using VSTS 2015. We get the following error in Visual Studio 2013:
"String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s"

It happens all the time when doing any of the following in Team Explorer:
* Click "Home", "Refresh", then "Builds"
* Click "Home", "Pending changes" giving this error message.

Comment: What's the VSTS2015? VSTS(https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) is  cloud offering  unlike TFS the on-premises offering ALM system.

Comment: How about other colleagues? Did they also got the same error info? If not, this should be a client issue.

Comment: Yes, others also getting the same issue. VSTS is visual studio team service on Cloud.

Comment: When you get the error info, which one are you actually connecting with? TFS or VSTS. And what's version 2015 mean? VSTS do not have 2015 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) on your develop machine.

Since this is not a client issue and occurs after TFS sever upgrade, double check if it will also occurs with other team project collection.

If the issue only with the specific collection, please detach the collection and use the pre back up database to restore it back.

Comment: I am not able to do second step which is mentioned in provided link. Please suggest.

Comment: @Jayant Second step is used to reset user data. Such as [`/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx) Since others also getting the same issue, it may related to the sever side. Please see my update answer.

Comment: your first answer is correct to clear the cache or reset the VS settings but unfortunately steps are not useful. so i have used this link to reset the VS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Jayant Any update for this, did it work after resetting VS and clearing cache?

Comment: Yes, It is working smooth.I have tried to vote but unable to do that.